# MySql: how to use the output of the `show` command in a nested query?

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to use the output of the `show` command in a nested select query? If yes then how?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Please be more specific.

Comment: As Rahul mentioned, something like `select * from (show tables) xx;`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the output of the show command in a nested
>   select query?

Simple answer: NO; and if you at all try like below, you will surely get an compilation error.

```
select * from (show tables) xx;
```

But you can use system tables/view like `information_schema.tables` mostly as an alternative to get the job done. Like, if you are trying to do `select * from (show tables) xx;` then the alternative would be

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: Look in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. There are the most information you use

Comment: @BerndBuffen, is the information for me (or) for OP.